# Parsing a string into JS language as well as parsing string into json or xml

Tags: javascript

***Update on 16 Jan 2021***

I have looked at this question later, finding that it is a silly question, as we can evaluate js code using `eval`, or by constructing a function

```js
new Function(...paramsAsString, codeAsString)
```

BTW, here is a bud-version of the [app](https://plotto.netlify.com) I was working on.

---

I want to create a simple graphing calculator, the user will put the
mathematical expression into an input element, js will reach it using input.value :

```
let input = document.querySelector('#text');
```

while drawing the function I can use `eval(...);` but it is so slow,
so I will be so grateful if you have any way to store some string looks like this
("x => " + "sin(x)") into a variable that is a function,

```
let expr = parseJS("x => " + "sin(x)");
console.log(expr(PI));
// 1
```

Comment: Ah, like `eval("x => " + "sin(x)")`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't expressed it correctly,

Comment: See the edited question.

Comment: The edited question looks the same. `let expr = eval("x => " + "sin(x)"); console.log(expr(PI));`

Comment: If I use eval, the argument should be  string, I can use `eval('sin(x)'.replace('x',<num>) ;`, but it would be slow, if I use `let expr= x => sin(x) ;` the performance will speed up.

Comment: I need a method to convert with the string "x=>sin(x) " into a function `x=>sin(x) `

Comment: Except never use `eval`, it's an insanely insecure function call. Instead, don't roll your own and simply pick one of several javascript "string to mathematical function" libraries already out there? E.g https://mathjs.org/docs/getting_started.html etc or if you really need symbolic expressions, https://www.npmjs.com/package/expr-eval etc

Comment: Why do you think `eval()` will be slow? It does exactly what the JavaScript compiler does when it's loading your script.

Comment: That’s why you don’t use `eval('sin(x)'.replace('x',<num>)`. You use `eval('x => ' + 'sin(x)')`, exactly like you asked for.

Comment: @Barmer `eval`  is slow when using it in `for(let i = 0; i < width; ++i)`, for all the function stored, if there is many functions to draw, it would be a nightmare,,, in the contrary, on making the variable `expr` a js funcrion that gets the value of x then returns the value of y, it is more fast,,,

I have tried both ways.

Comment: `eval('x => ' + 'sin(x)')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, I have solved this problem and I want to share knowledge with you.
this is the code to get a variable as a JS function:

```js
var fucnsExprScript1 = document.createElement('script');
fucnsExprScript1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`let funcExpr = [(x => NaN)]`));
document.body.appendChild(fucnsExprScript1);
function generateJSfunction(text){
  let func = `funcExpr.push(x => ${text});`;
  let fucnsExprScript2 = document.createElement('script');
  fucnsExprScript2.textContent = func;  
  document.body.appendChild(fucnsExprScript2);
  fucnsExprScript2.remove();
  return funcExpr[funcExpr.length - 1];
}
```

By this you can convert any string you want into any supported programming lang you want while the web is live.

You can also put a tea-area element and let users to type js code to handle by clicking a button.

This is after reflecting deep.

---

### Edition

the hereabove code is quite stupid, when I typed it I had not enough knowledge about the native function "eval", so the answer is:

```js
function getJSfuntion(str){
  return eval("x => " + str);
  // or 
  // return Function("x", `return {str};`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

would something like this be what you are looking for?

```js
let expr = x => Math.sin(x);

function btnSubmit(){
  let input = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#text').value);
  alert( expr(input) );
}
```

```html
  Enter a number: <input id="text" type="number" step="any">
  <input type="submit" onclick="btnSubmit()">
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the `input.value` will be "sin(x)"

Comment: What is the value of x?